# C# gridView multiple objects in json

Tags: c#, json, gridview

I'm showing successful data within my grid:

Like this:

**Form:**

```
json = response.Content;
var ticketWrapper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TicketWrapper(json);
```

**TicketWrapper:**

```
class TicketWrapper
{
   public IEnumerable<Tickets> tickets { get; set; }
}
```

**Tickets:**

```
class Tickets
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Json:

```
{
  "tickets": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Error bij compileren.",
      "description": "Bij het compileren van mijn c# applicatie krijg ik een error. ",
      "user_id": 1,
      "subject_id": 1,
      "status_id": 1,
      "status": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "In afwachting"
      },
      "subject": {
        "id": 1,
        "subject": "C#"
      },
      "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "email": "test@gmail.com",
        "company": "production",
        "role_id": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": "2016-09-08 08:22:07"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So my question:

How would I show the `name` of a `user`. I already tried something like this:

```
 class Tickets
 {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: You can generate poco objects from json here http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Ticket` class is incomplete.

Pasting your Json into http://json2csharp.com returns this class hierarchy (edited to remove superfluous data)

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public Subject subject { get; set; }
    public User user { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Ticket> tickets { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Subject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string subject { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public int role_id { get; set; }
    public object created_at { get; set; }
    public string updated_at { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have deserialized to this, the user name would be accessible via `ticket.User.name`